# Magento Admin URL 404

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

**I know that that similar issues and topics exist, however my issue differs slightly and none of the proposed fixes have worked.**

I was accessing the Magento backend as normal. Approximately 10 minutes after that I could no longer access the Magento backend.

What I mean is that when I go to the admin url login page, I get a 404. However the 404 isn't generated by my host, it's generated by my webstore.

Everything about my webstore works as normal.

I've seen a number of fixes, mainly this one...

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/207981/#t274443

I have a few main issues.

- Admin Custom URL had been set (but not by me). It was set over a year ago when Magento was installed. It worked entirely fine until today.
- I do not even have "admin/url/custom" and "admin/url/use_custom" in my "core_config_data" PHP table. It simply does not exist so I cannot change it. I looked manually for it and did a search for it. Nothing.
- I tried updating the local.xml file and clearing "var/caches" and "var/sessions" but that did not work either.

I've been working this for hours and it's beyond frustrating. It's imperative that this be fixed ASAP because we are a fairly sizeable company.

Thanks ahead for helping. Anything at all would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you do in this 10 minutes? Do you use ssl for admin?

Answer (score 1):

### First Check your Apache configurations

I know that you said you were only in the Magento admin but I would first check that apache was configured correctly. This is the first point of contact and you need to ensure that it's working right.

You need to locate a default Magento htaccess file that you can upload to your server. There's additional configurations that you need to make if you're in a subdirectory and also check to make sure that your mod_rewrite is working properly. There's an extensive tutorial on these things here, [magento htaccess](http://magentosupport.help/knowledgebase/magento-admin-login-shows-404-error/).

**Make sure that you have the right magento admin url**

I have to assume that you know what your magento admin url is, but of course I would double check that you're getting it right. There is an option in the admin area to change the admin url, you could have adjusted that on accident.

You say that you don't have "admin/url/custom" and "admin/url/use_custom" in your core_config_data table. This actually means that you didn't set the magento admin url from the admin area. However there is a third place that you can look for your admin url. This is in app/etc/local.xml but you couldn't have changed this from the administration area.

**Did you turn off search engine friendly urls?**

If you had been accessing your administrative area using /admin and then accidentally turned off SEF urls, then your admin area could have just simply moved to /index.php/admin. Of course you mentioned that you have a custom admin url, but I don't know what that is, so I'm giving examples with the default.

I can't really give you any more suggestions without more information. I hope that this helps!

Answer (score -2):

Found this and thought I would post here since it shows up in google.

http://sourcelibrary.org/2011/05/19/magento-404-page-not-found-error-for-admin-panel-access/#comment-8444

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.